# Writing table to memory in ArcPy gives ERROR 000354

Tags: arcpy, in-memory, error-000354, write

Currently I try to improve an ArcPy script which is run outside ArcGIS Pro 2.5 in Spyder.

I want to write a table to memory using the Table to Table tool. This tool is placed inside a loop and writes a new table to my workspace for every run.

Part of my code:

```
#Defining output path
output = "Routebestand_portaal_"+str(nummer_portaal)+"_selectie"
portalen_join_met_totaal = arcpy.AddJoin_management(in_layer_or_view="Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy",
                                                in_field="Portal_OBJECTID", join_table=Portaal_vultabel,
                                                join_field="Portal_OBJECTID", join_type="KEEP_COMMON")[0]

Portaal_vultabel = r"C:\Users\Work\Portalen_met_intensiteit"

#Write table to gdb
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(in_rows=portalen_join_met_totaal, out_name= output, where_clause="", field_mapping="Van___naar \"Van___naar\" true true false 200 Text 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy.Van___naar,0,200;VTGKM_VWH \"VTGKM_VWH\" true true false 8 Double 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy.VTGKM_VWH,-1,-1;Portal_OBJECTID \"Portal_OBJECTID\" true true false 4 Long 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy.Portal_OBJECTID,-1,-1;SUM_VTGKM_TOT \"SUM_VTGKM_TOT\" true true false 8 Double 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Portalen_met_intensiteit.SUM_VTGKM_TOT,-1,-1;SUM_VTGKM_VWH \"SUM_VTGKM_VWH\" true true false 8 Double 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Portalen_met_intensiteit.SUM_VTGKM_VWH,-1,-1", config_keyword="")[0]
```

..this code works and writes the table to my workspace. Now I want to write the table to memory.

---

My first approach was figure out how to write a table to memory outside a loop and without considering the variable output:

```
#Approach1  - using 'memory'
output1 = r"memory\tmpTable"     
portalen_join_met_totaal = arcpy.AddJoin_management(in_layer_or_view="Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy",
                                                in_field="Portal_OBJECTID", join_table=Portaal_vultabel,
                                                join_field="Portal_OBJECTID", join_type="KEEP_COMMON")[0]

Portaal_vultabel = r"C:\Users\Work\Portalen_met_intensiteit"           

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(in_rows=portalen_join_met_totaal, out_name= output1, where_clause="", field_mapping="Van___naar \"Van___naar\" true true false 200 Text 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy.Van___naar,0,200;VTGKM_VWH \"VTGKM_VWH\" true true false 8 Double 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy.VTGKM_VWH,-1,-1;Portal_OBJECTID \"Portal_OBJECTID\" true true false 4 Long 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy.Portal_OBJECTID,-1,-1;SUM_VTGKM_TOT \"SUM_VTGKM_TOT\" true true false 8 Double 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Portalen_met_intensiteit.SUM_VTGKM_TOT,-1,-1;SUM_VTGKM_VWH \"SUM_VTGKM_VWH\" true true false 8 Double 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Portalen_met_intensiteit.SUM_VTGKM_VWH,-1,-1", config_keyword="")[0]
```

..or these lines:

```
#Approach2 - using 'in_memory'
output2 = r"in_memory\tmpTable"
portalen_join_met_totaal = arcpy.AddJoin_management(in_layer_or_view="Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy",
                                                in_field="Portal_OBJECTID", join_table=Portaal_vultabel,
                                                join_field="Portal_OBJECTID", join_type="KEEP_COMMON")[0]

Portaal_vultabel = r"C:\Users\Work\Portalen_met_intensiteit"

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(in_rows=portalen_join_met_totaal, out_name= output2, where_clause="", field_mapping="Van___naar \"Van___naar\" true true false 200 Text 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy.Van___naar,0,200;VTGKM_VWH \"VTGKM_VWH\" true true false 8 Double 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy.VTGKM_VWH,-1,-1;Portal_OBJECTID \"Portal_OBJECTID\" true true false 4 Long 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy.Portal_OBJECTID,-1,-1;SUM_VTGKM_TOT \"SUM_VTGKM_TOT\" true true false 8 Double 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Portalen_met_intensiteit.SUM_VTGKM_TOT,-1,-1;SUM_VTGKM_VWH \"SUM_VTGKM_VWH\" true true false 8 Double 0 0,First,#,C:\\Users\\Work\\Data.gdb\\Routebestand_200605_totaalbestand_opgeschoond_copy,Portalen_met_intensiteit.SUM_VTGKM_VWH,-1,-1", config_keyword="")[0]
```

..both the options delivered an error message:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (TableToTable).
```

What I would like to get is something like `r"memory\   + "Routebestand_portaal_" + str(nummer_portaal) + "_selectie"`

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [tool documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm), Table to Table is setup with an output location and an output name parameter. As you're using it right now, you're trying to pass both the path and name in a single parameter.

Try something like:

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("vegtable.dbf", "memory", "vegtable")
```

or in your case

```
# output2 = just the output name, not the path
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(in_rows=portalen_join_met_totaal, out_path="memory", out_name= output2, where_clause="", ......
```