# Using ArcPy to Generate Near Table in memory

Tags: arcpy, python, proximity, error-000732, error-000210

I have a point SHP in WGS84 (EPSG 4326) and I am trying to tabulate the distances to the nearest point in meters. I need to do the analysis using ArcPy, but I want to get the results in a Pandas dataframe to do other things.

I'm stuck on getting the `GenerateNearTable_analysis()` in an in-memory format (throws the error below). And then from there, I actually don't know how to pass it into a dataframe.

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

filein = [
    r'D:\mypath\test1.shp',
    r'D:\mypath\test2.shp',
]

for f in filein:
    fout = f.replace(".shp", "")
    TempTab = 'in_memory\\{}_Table'.format(fout)
    arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(f, f, TempTab, method='GEODESIC')
```

Above throws this error:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output in_memory\D:\mypath\test_Table
Failed to execute (GenerateNearTable).
```

I also tried `arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(f, TempTab, "memory", method='GEODESIC')` as suggested in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365155/writing-table-to-memory-in-arcpy), and got the following error: `arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Near Features: Dataset 'in_memory\D:\mypath\test_Table' does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (GenerateNearTable).`

Using ArcMap 10.7

Comment: At the moment you’re stuck on the ArcPy step that precedes what you’re trying to do with pandas. I think you should look at that 000210 error message and the invalid path it reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of the directory as well as the file extension.

```
import os

import arcpy
import pandas as pd

filein = [
    r'D:\mypath\test1.shp',
    r'D:\mypath\test2.shp',
]

for f in filein:
    fout = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]  #<=== strip file extension and path
    TempTab = 'in_memory\\{}_Table'.format(fout)
    arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(f, f, TempTab, method='GEODESIC')
```

Comment: Solved the issue, thank you. I added `cols = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(temp)]` ... `mydf = pd.DataFrame(arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(in_table=temp, field_names=cols, skip_nulls=False, null_value=-99999))` to get it into a Pandas dataframe